# File as command line argument for argparse - error message if argument is empty

Tags: python, argparse

I am currently using argparse like this:

```
def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
if not os.path.exists(arg):
    parser.error("Tep tin %s khong ton tai!" % arg)
else:
    return open(arg, 'rb')   

def readinput():
parser = ArgumentParser(description="ikjMatrix multiplication")
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="filename", required=True,
                    help="File need predict", metavar="FILE",
                    type=lambda x: is_valid_file(parser, x))
args = parser.parse_args()
return args.filename.read()
```

I want to check if a file is empty ? and if a file valid?I checked a valid file then i would like check if the file is empty, I would like to get an error message. How can I do that? please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.stat` (here, accessed via a `Path` object) to check the file size.

```
from argparse import ArgumentTypeError, ArgumentParser
from pathlib import Path


def NonEmptyFile(s):
    p = Path(s)
    if p.stat().st_size == 0:
        raise ArgumentTypeError(f'{s} cannot be empty')
    return p


def readinput():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="ikjMatrix multiplication")
    parser.add_argument("-i", dest="filename", required=True,
                help="File need predict", metavar="FILE",
                type=NonEmptyFile)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return p.read_text()   # Or read_bytes, as appropriate
```

---

To avoid a race condition (where someone could empty the file *after* you have determined it isn't empty), read from the file first, then check if you read anything or not.

```
def FileContents(s):
    try:
        with open(s) as f:
            data = f.read()  # Decode, if desired
    except Exception as exc:
        raise ArgumentTypeError(f"Problem reading from {s}") from exc

    if len(data) == 0:
        raise ArgumentTypeError(f"{s} cannot be empty")
    return data

def readinput():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="ikjMatrix multiplication")
    parser.add_argument("-i", dest="data", required=True,
                help="File need predict", metavar="FILE",
                type=FileContents)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return p.data
```

Comment: This answer does what OP asked for, but note that there is a race between the input validation and when we actually start to work on the file. It may be best to open the file before verifying that it is not zero-length.

Comment: Very good point; I had considered reading from the file immediately (though not for that reason), then opted to keep the filename (or at least, the `Path`-object equivalent) as the argument value to avoid changing the original too much.